# Relation between linux/arm64 and linux/arm64/v8: are these aliases for each other?

Tags: docker

I have a question about the architecture of docker images.

For example, `alpine:latest` provides the image for [`linux/arm/v8`](https://hub.docker.com/layers/alpine/library/alpine/latest/images/sha256-c74f1b1166784193ea6c8f9440263b9be6cae07dfe35e32a5df7a31358ac2060?context=explore) architecture.
We can pull this image by specifying the `linux/arm64` platform:

```
$ docker pull --platform linux/arm64 alpine
$ docker image inspect alpine
...
        "Architecture": "arm64",
        "Variant": "v8",
        "Os": "linux",
...
```

I figured out that this result implies `linux/arm64` is an alias for `linux/arm64/v8`.
In another experiments, I found the following similar behaviors:

- `--platform linux/arm/v8` pulls `linux/arm64` image
- `--platform linux/arm` pulls `linux/arm/v7` image
- `--platform linux/arm/v7` pulls `linux/arm` image

Could you please explain the definition of such aliases, or the rules for resolving the architecture? Or is there an official guide?

Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I got my own answer to this topic, so let me share it.

1. In [the reference page for `docker buildx build` command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/buildx_build/#platform), we can find the following statement:

   > The formatting for the platform specifier is defined in the [containerd source code](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/v1.4.3/platforms/platforms.go#L63).
2. Open that link. There exists a detailed description of the platform notation. In short,

   - A notation might be normalized by certain rules.
   - The omitted parts can be inferred under certain conditions.

That's almost all I needed.

---

**Appendix**

- The platform `linux/arm64/v8` [will be normalized](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/v1.4.3/platforms/database.go#L83) as `linux/arm64`.
- The default variant for `arm` architecture is [`v7`](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/v1.4.3/platforms/platforms.go#L101).
- We can omit the OS part; it will be inferred:

  ```sh
  $ docker pull --platform 386 alpine
  $ docker image inspect alpine --format '{{.Os}}/{{.Architecture}}'
  linux/386
  ```
- There is a normalization rule:

  ```sh
  $ docker pull --platform x86_64 alpine
  $ docker image inspect alpine --format '{{.Os}}/{{.Architecture}}'
  linux/amd64
  $ docker pull --platform aarch64 alpine
  $ docker image inspect alpine --format '{{.Os}}/{{.Architecture}}'
  linux/arm64
  ```

Comment: I guess the follow up question would be: what happens when (if ever) there is a arm64/v9? Will arm64 then suddenly map to arm64/v9? So would it be better to be explicit and reference the exact version whenever we can?

Answer (score 6):

The [Docker documentation](https://github.com/docker-library/official-images#architectures-other-than-amd64) has this list:

```
Architectures other than amd64?

Some images have been ported for other architectures, and many of these are officially supported (to various degrees).

    Architectures officially supported by Docker, Inc. for running Docker: (see download.docker.com)
        ARMv6 32-bit (arm32v6): https://hub.docker.com/u/arm32v6/
        ARMv7 32-bit (arm32v7): https://hub.docker.com/u/arm32v7/
        ARMv8 64-bit (arm64v8): https://hub.docker.com/u/arm64v8/
        Linux x86-64 (amd64): https://hub.docker.com/u/amd64/
        Windows x86-64 (windows-amd64): https://hub.docker.com/u/winamd64/
    Other architectures built by official images: (but not officially supported by Docker, Inc.)
        ARMv5 32-bit (arm32v5): https://hub.docker.com/u/arm32v5/
        IBM POWER8 (ppc64le): https://hub.docker.com/u/ppc64le/
        IBM z Systems (s390x): https://hub.docker.com/u/s390x/
        MIPS64 LE (mips64le): https://hub.docker.com/u/mips64le/
        RISC-V 64-bit (riscv64): https://hub.docker.com/u/riscv64/
        x86/i686 (i386): https://hub.docker.com/u/i386/
```

Comment: This does not seem to answer my question. For example, `linux/arm64` and `linux/arm` are not explicitly described. How should I understand that?

Comment: There is exactly one ARM 64 bit architecture on the list - v8 - so we can infer that arm64 == v8. There are several ARM 32 bit architectures on the list - v5, v6, and v7 - so one can either specify a particular one, or (apparently) use the default equation arm == arm32 == v7 (the latest 32 bit architecture). There's some speculation here, but I think it's reasonable.

Comment: @ atrocia6 Thank you for your comment. Yes, I agree with you, but I am looking for **evidence**... Can anyone help?