# Docker compose platform conflict

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I just have upgraded my Docker application on my Mac M1 and I have a new issue.

"Error response from daemon: image with reference mariadb was found but does not match the specified platform: wanted linux/amd64, actual: linux/arm64/v8"

I would like to force "linux/amd64".

I have tried without any success:

```
export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0                                                                                                                                                    
export COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD=0
export DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64
```

As per your information :

```
$ docker compose version
Docker Compose version v2.23.3-desktop.2
```

Mac OS: 12.5.1.

I see a lot of answers around `docker buildx` about how to build for a different architecture using the `--platform` flag. But here `mariadb` is just an image from docker hub.

Comment: Related, but not a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70819028/relation-between-linux-arm64-and-linux-arm64-v8-are-these-aliases-for-each-othe

Comment: Have you tried pulling the mariadb image with the `--platform` flag and using it?
```docker pull --platform linux/amd64 mariadb```

Comment: @oldmanowl I manually pulled this image (and another) and now `docker compose up -d` does not complete anymore. Do you wish to make an answer out of your comment? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's also possible to set `platform: linux/amd64` in the service declared in the docker-compose file.

Comment: @AsTeR I guess you need to also specify this image in your docker compose. Let me make an answer with some more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `docker pull [image name]` you can use the `--platform` flag to specify a platform. In your case you should use: `docker pull --platform linux/amd64 mariadb` and make also changes in your `docker-compose.yml` file. In the service declaration which is using mariadb, you also need to specify the platform:

```
services:
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb
    platform: linux/amd64
```